# Exclude include?

Tags: обсуждение, вопросы

Наткнулся на такой [комментарий](//ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/605401/%d0%9f%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b5-%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%be-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%bc%d1%8b?noredirect=1#comment824177_605401):

> Перенесите текст из картинки в вопрос, сделайте пример минималистичным (то есть, к примеру, удалите include, int main), оставьте суть. Также отформатируйте код, чтобы было сходу понятно что происходит в программе. Опишите что нужно, а что получается/не получается. Помогите отвечающим вам помочь. – Vadim Ovchinnikov 1 час назад

Собственно, я не согласен с этой позицией - есть целая программа, а есть кусок кода. Неужели действительно есть смысл ради этих нескольких строк кода превращать цельную программу в какой-то ошмёток кода? Какую пользу это даёт?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Иногда лишний обвес в виде необходимых `#include` действительно не нужен и очевиден, но иногда это может быть важно. Т.е. надо в каждом случае принимать решение отдельно. При этом часто для проверки проблемы ТС нужно запустить его код. И в этом случае намного лучше, если код самодостаточный, т.е. его можно скопировать и, не добавляя больше ни символа, выполнить сборку в одном из онлайн-компиляторов. Если для этого нужно самому добавлять `main`, необходимые инклюды или что-то ещё, это может оттолкнуть от желания помогать автору. Более того, может получится несколько иной результат. Например, проблема вообще не проявится, а всё потому, что ТС не смог предоставить [MCVE](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). В таком случае вопрос вовсе может быть закрыт с причиной "проблема вызвана опечаткой" или что-то подобное.

Comment: Для сравнения: посмотрите, как питонисты делают. Я не очень хорошо разбираюсь в pyton, но сколько попадаются на глаза их вопросы-ответы в очереди проверок - там как раз не отрезают include'ы. Видимо, так принято  у них.

Answer (score 6):

Когда программа только состоит из метода `main` и чего-то тривиального и стандартного вроде процедур `printf`, то совершенно очевидно что предлагаемый фрагмент кода вызывается в методе `main` и нужны соответствующие директивы.

> Неужели действительно есть смысл ради этих нескольких строк кода превращать цельную программу в какой-то ошмёток кода?

Ну если программа не такая простая, то цельность в любом случае будет нарушена. Неужели надо давать тысячи строк кода дополнительно ради цельности? Даже если программа изначально сложна и громоздка, то ради вопроса, по моему мнению, она должна быть упрощена и содержать только нужные для вопроса фрагменты.

Вопрос должен быть ясным и минимальным. И удаление этих строк кода улучшает понимание программы (лично моё мнение). В книгах по программированию в примерах кода очень часто опускают метод `main` и тривиальные директивы и ясность от этого не теряется, напротив увеличивается информативность. Зато фокус сразу на деталях.

Я думаю, что если человек не вчера прочитал, что такое C++, то вряд ли не сможет разобраться без этого.

Comment: Могут быть моменты типа обнуления глобальных переменных, например. Пишешь одним способом - работает, а другим - нет. А у совсем тривиальных программ эти 4 строчки ничему не мешают ведь.

Comment: @Qwertiy Я написал "только состоит из метода main", поэтому если есть глобальные переменные и т.д. и т.п, то вполне _может быть_ и имеет смысл эти вещи оставить. Но именно для обычных программ, для чего-то тривиального, я не вижу смысла.

Comment: А как отличить-то, если автор удалит main? Часто массивы отправляют в глобальную область, чтоб стек не жрали.

Comment: Ну у автора должен быть развит разум, чтобы отличать случаи когда уместно это упрощение, когда нет.